# Storyboard size on iPhone6 after update

Tags: ios, xcode, storyboard, iphone-6

I take a old app with a 3 storyboard inside:

> iPhone4 || iPhone5 || iPad

at the moment from the AppStore this working well on iPhone6 and 6Plus even if not have `iPhone6.storyboard` inside show in full screen correct position, but now during the test on iPhone6 (device not simulator) is showing a 4.0 inches inside a big display of 4.7 inches, here the screen:

[image]

I Know is better using a new system with Auto Resize and Size Classes but at the moment we don't have time to do a refactor.

So this is my question, is possibile reuse my `iPhone5.storyboard` as before to see all stuff inside in a correct position, neve use Auto Layout and Size Classes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It may be possible, by not using a launch image `.xib` file. In that case, your app appears zoomed on the iPhone 6. That is why your existing app looks okay on iPhone 6: it doesn't have a launch image `.xib` file. So you could solve the issue by deleting the launch image `.xib` file and telling the app to use old-fashioned launch images instead.

But that, as you rightly say, is not really correct behavior; eventually, Apple will probably forbid it.